# Affilinet SOAP WSDL php script --> Output to CSV

Tags: php, xml, csv, soap, wsdl

following up my other question, I have here an php script with a SOAP WSDL request to get the voucher codes from Affilinet. The php example works and the output is an array.

How can I get an .csv file from it?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

// Set webservice endpoints
define("WSDL_LOGON", "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl");
define("WSDL_WS", "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/PublisherInbox.svc? wsdl");

// Set credentials
$username = 'xxxxxx'; // the publisher ID
$password = 'xxxxxxx'; // the publisher web services password

// Send a request to the Logon Service to get an authentication token
$soapLogon = new SoapClient(WSDL_LOGON);
$token = $soapLogon->Logon(array(
'Username'  => $username,
'Password'  => $password,
'WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'
));

// Set DisplaySettings parameters
$displaySettings = array(
'CurrentPage' => 1,
'PageSize' => 1000,
'SortBy' => 'LastChangeDate',
'SortOrder' => 'Descending'
);

// Set SearchVoucherCodesRequestMessage parameters
$params = array(
'StartDate' => strtotime("now"),
'EndDate' => strtotime("now"),
'VoucherCodeContent' => 'Filled',

);

// Send a request to the Publisher Inbox Service
$soapRequest = new SoapClient(WSDL_WS);
$response = $soapRequest->SearchVoucherCodes(array(
'CredentialToken' => $token,
'DisplaySettings' => $displaySettings,
'SearchVoucherCodesRequestMessage' => $params
));

// Show response
//print_r($response);


/*

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
*/


$file = fopen("gutscheine.csv","w");

foreach ($response as $line)
{
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
}

fclose($file); ?>
```

The last bit is my attempt to create the csv. The csv file is created but nothing is in there.

I am not good at php, so please be patient :)

Thanks,
Karolin